# Android how to check content of Image View using Espresso

Tags: android, imageview, android-espresso

I am loading an image into an image view from a URL using Glide.
How do I do perform a comparison operation on this image view to check that the correct URL has indeed been loaded using Espresso ?
I have a number of such images in a recycler view and am scrolling to each of its items like this :

```
for(int i=0;i<length;i++){

            onView(withId(R.id.people_recycler_view)).perform(RecyclerViewActions.scrollToPosition(i));

        }
```

But in this loop how do I perform a check for the image view content ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

An easy (but not exactly complete) way to do this is to add an appropriate content description wherever the image is being set in the application source code and then using `onView(withContentDescription("Cute Picture Of Cat"));`

If that doesn't cut it, add the expected image in your test project and use an image comparison library to compare it with whatever you see within the bounds of the element on the screen.

eg - Create and use a custom matcher like below. You will also have to write your own Image comparison method.

```
onView(withId(R.id.myElementThatHasImage)).
    CustomMatcher.compareImages(test.R.id.myExpectedImageID));

public static Matcher<Object> compareImages(Matcher<View> expectedImageView) {
    return new TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {

        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {
            description.appendText("comparingImages");
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean matchesSafely(View actualImageView) {
            return MyCompareLibrary.compare(expectedImageView,(ImageView)actualImageView.getDrawable());
        }
    };
}
```